# Matching bash variables as number literals with grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a (GNU) bash script which establishes two variables to be matched in a file.

```
hour=$(head -n 1 sensorstest.log | cut -f5 | cut -d"-" -f1)
dom=$(head -n 1 sensorstest.log | cut -f5 | cut -d"-" -f4)
```

...and matches them to other occurrences in the file

```
grep -E [^0-9]+"$hour"-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-"$dom"-[0-9]+-[0-9]{4} sensorstest.log
```

Here is an example of the script calculating the mean for all values in field 2 of the input file for the given hour of day.

```
hMean=$(grep -E [^0-9]+"$hour"-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-"$dom"-[0-9]+-[0-9]{4} sensorstest.log | cut -f2 | awk ' {sum+=$
1}{count++}{mean=sum/count} END {printf("%.2f",mean) } ' );
```

Here is an example of the cleanup of the input file.

```
echo "removing: "$hour"th hour of the "$dom"th day  of the "$month"th month"
sed -i -r '/'"$hour"'-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-'"$dom"'-'"$month"'-[0-9]{4}/d' sensorstest.log
```

And finally... Here is an example line in the file:

The format is:

*status<tab>humidity<tab>temperature<tab>unix timestamp<tab>time/date*

> OK    94.4    16.9    1443058486  1-34-46-24-9-2015

I am attempting to match all instances of the *hour* on the *day* of the first entry in the file.

This works fine for numbers below 9, however;

**Problem:** Numbers over 9 are being matched as two single digit numbers, resulting in 12 matching 1, 2, 12, 21...etc.

Here is an example of where is trips up:

> OK    100 17.2    1442570381  9-59-41-18-9-2015
>
> OK    100 17.1    1442570397  9-59-57-18-9-2015
>
> Moistening    100 17.6    1442574014  11-0-14-18-9-2015
>
> Moistening    100 17.6    1442574030  11-0-30-18-9-2015

Here the output skips to 0-0-0-19-9-2015 (and yes I am missing an hour of entries from the log)

```
$ sudo statanhourtest.sh

100,1.4,1.40,-98.6      16.5,17.2,16.90,.7      1442566811      9-0-0-18-9-2015

removing: 9th hour of the 18th day  of the 9th month
```

```
$ sudo statanhourtest.sh

100,1.4,1.40,-98.6      18.3,18.8,18.57,.5      1442620804      0-0-0-19-9-2015

removing: 0th hour of the 19th day  of the 9th month
```

The problem is only happening with the hours. the day `($dom)` is matching fine.

I have tried using the *-w* option with grep, but I think this only returns the exact match where I need the whole line.

There's not much online about matching numbers literally in grep. And I found nothing on using bash variables as a number literal.

Any help or relevant links would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have solved the problem after a night of dredging through the script.
The problem lay with my *sed* expression right at the end.
The problem being in single quoting parts of the sed expression and double quoting variables for expansion by the shell.
I took this from a suggestion on another thread.
Double quoting the whole expression solved the problem.

The *awk* suggestion has greatly increased the efficiency and accuracy of the script. Thanks again.

Comment: You'd be better off splitting the fields with awk, perl, or ruby for your comparisons. Numeric comparisons aren't ideal fodder for regular expressions.

Comment: hmm..so it would seem.
There is an awk expression after the pattern match which passes the entire matching line to awk for splitting and calculation.
Are you suggesting I could dispense with grep and cut, to do a line by line field split with awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

I think you can combine everything to a simple awk script without needing any regex.  For example,

```
awk 'NR==1{split($NF,h,"-")} {split($NF,t,"-")} t[1]==h[1] && t[4]==h[4]'
```

will parse the time stamp on the first row of the file and filters only the hour and day matching records.

This will take the average of field 2

```
awk 'NR==1
     {
          split($NF,h,"-")
     } 
     {             
          split($NF,t,"-")
     } 
     t[1]==h[1] && t[4]==h[4]
     {
          sum+=$2;
          c++
     } 
     END 
     {
          print "Average: " sum/c
     }'
```

Comment: Thank you karakfa! Crikey awk is quick. I am unclear on the use of == above. Whether it is like an if statement. But it works

Comment: awk scripts are a sequence of `condition{action}` blocks.